# jQuery conflict with Galleria and WordPress

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I whipped up a simple WP plugin for using the jQuery slider [plugin Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se). In a widget, header and footer the two seem to produce expected results.

However, when using my WP plugin via a shortcode in a post/page Galleria bombs when trying to create the thumbnails. For some reason it doesn't appended the height and width of that img element in the inline markup it creates. That in turn causes Galleria to display an error message:

```
Galleria.raise('Could not extract width/height from image: ' + img.src + '. Traced measures: width:' + img.width + 'px, height: ' + img.height + 'px.');
```

I've seen the question on Galleria's GetSatisfaction about the [AdBlock bug](http://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/issues/detail?id=3701). As a test, I even went so far as to try to hardcode the img.height and img.width in that area of the Galleria code just prior to: `Galleria.raise('Could not ..);`

In spite of my `img.width = "50"` the width continued to remain 0. Setting the height worked fine (but didn't squash the error because of the 0 width). I think there's some other missing inline styling of the thumbnails as well.

If it matters, I'm dev'ing my WP plugin while using the WP theme Twenty Eleven V1.1. I'm also using Instant WP as my client based dev environment.

Finally, I've tried Galleria for help but can't seem to make any progress. My feeling is they interpret my request as support for my plugin. That's not the case. I'm trying to troubleshoot their jQ plugin not producing as expected. What I'm trying to say is, I'm here because I have to be, not because I haven't already tried them for help.

If it helps, I can post a link to a copy of my WP plugin. I'm mainly interested in Galleria because it's free and it has a full screen mode. Once I resolve this I want to develop a WP plugin that use a shortcode to embed a Flckr based slideshow in a WP post/page. Resolving this is kinda a big issue for me.

Comment: Please, post the code for your shortcode and the code Galleria uses to "extract width/height from image", if you can find it.